# Cannot find data source to set data source for layers in MXD?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layers

I got some data in mxd format and when i try to open it:

[image]

I tried to set data source but i cannot find the data source because the orginal file was saved in H:\drive and i do not have h drive on my computer.

How can I solve this situation?

---

matter is the person its not available and  i have to find another way to open and access the data

Comment: Consider having a look at the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 4):

All I can suggest is that you find someone who knows where the data on that H: drive might be accessible on your system.

If it is, then review [Repairing broken data links](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/repairing-broken-data-links.htm).

If it is not, then ask whoever sent you the MXD to send the necessary folders of data so that you can repair its layers.

For a simplified workflow consider asking them for a [map package](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/creating-a-map-package.htm) (`*.mpk`) instead of a map (`*.mxd`) next time.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't get the data in MXD format, you got an MXD. MXD's do not contain the data, just references to the data.

Talk to whoever sent you the MXD and ask them for the data.

Comment: thanks for answering the thing is that MXD file has some layer as you can see in pic but data no how i can find data source to setting them

Comment: @amin your data source is H: drive - you can only view that data if you can see H: Drive or put the data somewhere you can access then point your layers at that

Answer (score 0):

A MXD contains references to the datasources. The only way to get the data is to ask the person who send you this MXD for the source data. Source data can be a shapefile, a GDB or other kind of sources.